# Deploy github pages with jekyll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've recently got a new job as an IT technician and I wanted to start a new blog where I will document my journey to IT. I decided to create a blog using GitHub pages because it was simple and easy to maintain. I searched and found the best template for my needs however, when I run `bundle exec jekyll s` I get this error:

```
To use retry middleware with Faraday v2.0+, install `faraday-retry` gem
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5-x64-mingw-ucrt/lib/ffi/library.rb:145:in `block in ffi_lib': 
  Could not open library 'libcurl': The specified module could not be found. (LoadError)
```

I then ran `gem install faraday-retry`, to install the missing gem followed by `bundle list`, to double check that the gem is installed but, I'm still getting the same error.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: When using bundler, you should add required gems to your [`Gemfile`](https://bundler.io/gemfile.html) and run `bundle install`.

Comment: the LoadError seems to be unrelated to the faraday-retry gem

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem you need to add the following line into your `gemfile`:

`gem 'faraday', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.11'`

It will install faraday during the build phase of your github-pages.

Your `gemfile` should look similar to this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'faraday', '~> 2.7', '>= 2.7.11'
gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
gem "jekyll-include-cache", group: :jekyll_plugins
```

Then you call it from `_config.yml`:

```
title: your website title
description: some description
google_analytics: 
show_downloads: true 
remote_theme: "mmistakes/minimal-mistakes@4.24.0"

plugins:
  - jekyll-include-cache
  - gemfile
```

**Side note:** the `gems` flag in the yaml file was deprecated and replaced by `plugins` in recent versions.

Comment: I needed to include `faraday-retry` in the `Gemfile` as well to solve this issue with Jekyll v3.9.3.